# C# UTC to local time convertion unexpected results

Tags: c#, timezone, timezone-offset

From yesterday (the first day of US day light saving adjustment had began.) the same code that runs on two different computers are giving different results. Here are the code:

```
DateTime t = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(
          DateTime.UtcNow, r.timeZone);
```

While timezone used here is "US Eastern Standard Time"

Input (DateTime.UtcNow) is 2012/03/13 19:10:00

On a windows XP SP3 machine the code returns: 2012/03/13 14:10:00

On a windows server 2008 machine the same code returns: 2012/03/13 15:10:00

This is not expected. Any thoughts?

Best.

Comment: Did you install all Windows Updates on both machines?

Comment: Stupid question, but did you run one test last week and one this week?  DST just took effect this weekend.

Comment: What is 'Windows server 2007'? =) Check if all DST patches are installed in XP SP3, I think XP returns wrong result.

Comment: last week XP machine returnes correct result. This week it's incorrect, mostly likely due to timezone issue

Comment: Compare registry keys "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\US Eastern Standard Time" between machines (TZI key)

Comment: @Slaks The return value is determined by the machine not the .Net runtime? Is this what you mean? And i dont have proper update on the XP machine?

Comment: @Artem They are the same. Values are : 0000 0008 0010 0018 0020 0028

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current time zone on the XP machine is "US Eastern *Standard* Time" while the current time zone on the Server machine is "US Eastern *Daylight* Time". The US changed from Standard to Daylight time on Sunday. Perhaps the XP machine needs to have its time zone information updated.

Comment: XP machine has timezone settings as GMT-5 and adjusted for daylight saving time. Currently the displayed time is correct. What information do you think need to be updated?

Comment: @Johnyy: As of March 11, the current time in the Eastern Time Zone is GMT-4. The XP machine does not have the correct Daylight Saving Time transition date. In 2007 the US changed when they transition in and out of Daylight time, so XP needs to be updated to reflect that.